# Problem when assigning Input.mousePosition to transform.position in Unity2D

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, input, transform

I have been following the Inventory tutorials for Unity by Kryzarel and have encountered a weird issue that I think may be from something unrelated.

Tons of googling has yielded no results. It seems like an obscure issue.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOM0GGMEcu-gyf4F1mT7A8Q/videos for reference of the channel.

But the issue I'm running into is I do the following:

```
draggableItem.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
```

So basically draggable Item is a reference to an Image component on a GameObject. I log Input.mousePosition before hand and the values make sense (within the hundreds e.g. (563,262,0)). However, the transform position is nowhere near the number logged. For the example, I'm seeing (48660.31, 23917.95, -7889.887). There is no logic between the debug.log statement giving Input.mousePosition and the code assigning it to the transform. Anyone have any idea what I could possibly have configured wrong, or could be wrong?

I would expect the position to be (563,262,0) not the ridiculous number that it ends up being. I've tried `localPosition` instead of `transform.position`, and it *sort of* works. In that it's off by about 500 or 700 to the top-right of what I'm moving relative to the mouse, I want to avoid hacky solutions like subtracting some magic number if possible.

Edit: Some further background, other mouse clicks and mouse related things appear to work correctly. It's an orthographic camera, or the default for a unity2D project

Solution: IN my case I was able to set it per the accepted answer, I then had to modify `position` not `localPosition` and also had to zero out the z-value of the world point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse position is relative to your screen, not your world. You need to convert the screen space to world space with:

```
 var pos = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question properly at first and don't think this will help you. I'll remove this if you'd confirm that it doesn't help.

Comment: Actually, that sort of worked halfway, between that and zeroing the z-value I was able to get it correct!!! Also had to move the UI element to anchor bottom-left, but it gave proper coords.

Comment: Wonderful! If you're working with Ui you might want to check out [ReactTransformUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.html)